# Django QuerySet OR with different annotations

Tags: django, django-models

When I retrieve two subsets of objects from the same model class `MyModel` and add different annotations to each (`something` to the first, `other` to the second -- neither of these attributes is a field in `MyModel`), I get strange results:

```
mgr = MyModel.objects
q1 = mgr.filter(pk=1).annotate(something= \
        djdm.Value("is", output_field=djdm.CharField(null=True)))
q2 = mgr.filter(pk=2).annotate(other= \
        djdm.Value(123, output_field=djdm.CharField(null=True)))
    queryset = q1 | q2
    print([(obj.pk, 
            getattr(obj, 'something', 'NO_something'),
            getattr(obj, 'other', 'NO_other'))
           for obj in queryset.all()])
```

With Django 2.1 on SQlite, what I am getting is:

> [(1, 'is', 'NO_other'), (2, 'is', 'NO_other')]

Questions:

1. I would have hoped for `None` instead of the first `'NOother'`. Is there a way to make Django add the `other` column from `q2` to `q1` in the OR?
2. The second `'NO_other'` is disappointing. Where did my `123` annotation go?
3. The second `'is'` is completely ridiculous. How can the `something` from `q1` possibly creep over to `q2`?? That makes no sense. What is going on there?

I am sure making some mistake here (at least I hope so), but which?

Comment: If you perform a `UNION`, the database columns should match. It looks furthermore to me as bad design to perform different annotations. Can't you annotate the items with `other=Value(None)` and vice versa to "inject" values?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My real situation is a lot more complex than the sketched one and I am evaluating how much I can simplify things. But apparently I will have to (and can) make the same annotations everywhere. Nevertheless, an answer to question 3 would be enlightnening.